# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mediapipe

I am trying very hard from a day and unable to find solution for this problem in my rassberry pi 4. i am using OS of 32 bit (rassbian bullseye). Do anyone has solution for this issue ??

```
from mediapipe.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mediapipe/python/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'
```

Comment: Not medapipe.python. Don't' do this import*. It is better use this import mediapipe